# How can I change the Oauth token algorithm type form RS256 to HS256 in azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to implement the SSO for Zendesk using Azure AD B2C. I am getting the JWT token in  the Url but it's encryption algorithm type is RS256 which is not supportable by zendesk so how can I change it from RS246 to HS256 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom policies (Identity Experience Framework), you can generate your won HS256 key and use it.

Copy the below JSON content in a .json file (ex: TOkenSigningKeyContainerHS256.json)

```
{
"keys": [
    {
        "kty": "oct",
        "kid": "3092fb56-b2fb-44a9-a037-0bfee7f957bb",
        "k": "cuU_Pbb3nSCLXgboggAyNFsHjxTBOxKCxdD2Sa0mTb8",
        "alg": "HS256"
    }
]
```

}

Upload this file against IEF -> Policy Keys (Policy Keys -> Add -> choose Upload) by giving valid key name.

In your TrustFrameworkBaseFile, find for **B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer** key and replace with your newly created key.

**Note** Above is a blind replacing of key and that will work in most of the cases. If not you can update specific Technical Profile `<TechnicalProfile Id="JwtIssuer">` that is used to issue JWToken

if you are using refresh token mechanism then you need to update that keys also.

After your successful user journey, JWT token will be returned and that will be signed using HS256.

Comment: I have tried this but still is not working,It still give me the RS256 as Oauth algorithm type

Comment: Are you using your custom TechnicalProfile for issuing tokens?

Comment: No , I am not using TechnicalProfile