# Azure B2C OAuth vs Hubspot JWT

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, jwt, hubspot, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure B2C instance configured. We use the Identity Experience Framework, because of some custom user journeys we have configured.
In Hubspot, I am trying to verify SSO for private content on websites.
I need to set up Single Sign On based on JWT in Hubspot
https://knowledge.hubspot.com/website-pages/set-up-single-sign-on-sso-to-access-private-content

In Azure B2C I have configured a secret key. I entered this secret key inside the HubSpot configuration page. But this page only recognizes the key as HS256 and not as RS256. So I select HS256.

[image]

The id_token which I got back from AzureB2C, to Hubspot, has the following header

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "VHk1fkTeXwU9BUfQ_19VUi2cwM0ONJPcUbttMJNmTx8",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

When the id_token is sent back to hubspot (after a successful user journey), the user gets redirected back to https://xxxx.eu/_hcms/mem/jwt/verify#id_token=eyJhbGcixxxxxxxxxx .etc
And then the error below pops-up.

The documentation of hubspot tells me:

TOKEN_VERIFICATION_FAILED: token may be empty, null, incorrect, or the query parameter is unsupported. We support “jwt”, “code”, “id_token”, and “access_token” query parameters.

[image]

I think this is because its alg: is set to RS256.
I have tried to change it to HS256 but, I am stuck in that process. There 3 small posts about it, but now I don't know what I can do... Some posts also tell me that Azure B2C only support RSA?

[Azure AD B2C - Token validation does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330242/azure-ad-b2c-token-validation-does-not-work)
and
[Validate Azure B2C tokens with symmetric HS256 secrets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71589673/validate-azure-b2c-tokens-with-symmetric-hs256-secrets)
[How can I change the Oauth token algorithm type form RS256 to HS256 in azure portal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59247254/how-can-i-change-the-oauth-token-algorithm-type-form-rs256-to-hs256-in-azure-por?rq=2)

The last post looks promising, but that doesn't work.

Update:
**After some more digging I found the following posts from almost a year ago**
https://community.hubspot.com/t5/APIs-Integrations/JWT-SSO-for-Private-Content-Invalid-Requirements-and-AWS-Cognito/td-p/517582

https://community.hubspot.com/t5/APIs-Integrations/JWT-SSO-for-private-content-invalid-secret-key-for-RS256-signing/m-p/622696

Does anyone have some experience with this problem?

Comment: Sounds like you would need to configure the RS256 key in Hubspot, though that seems awfully brittle considering that B2C publishes their signing keys on an endpoint where they could just read them from.. What options does the UI give if you select RS256? What did you try to enter there?

Comment: When I choose RS256 in HubSpot, I still have only the secret key field (just like the screenshot). But I can't find any documentation around that field with RS256. But it doesn't accept my secret key (generated in Azure B2C) anymore. 
When I set it to HS256, it accepts my secret generated from Azure B2C (app registration)

Comment: After more digging... I found this
https://community.hubspot.com/t5/APIs-Integrations/JWT-SSO-for-Private-Content-Invalid-Requirements-and-AWS-Cognito/td-p/517582
It looks like the same issue....